# Is the word "on" pronounced like /ʌn/ or /ən/ instead of /ɔn/ when it is unstressed?

Tags: grammar, pronunciation, vocabulary, weak-forms

Is the word "on" pronounced like /ʌn/ or /ən/ instead of /ɔn/ when it is unstressed in an American accent?

Comment: I think you're right. That's is essentially the same question.

Answer (score 1):

No, *on* does not have a weak form. It is always pronounced with a full vowel as /ɒn/ (mainly British English), /ɑn/ (American English without low back merger), /ɔn/, etc.

Here are some sources sharing this view:

- "Note: There is no weak form for on /ɒn/." (from: Low, E. (2015) [*Pronunciation for English as an International Language*.](https://books.google.ch/books?id=i0aDBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT118&lpg=PT118&dq=%22no+weak+form+for+on%22&source=bl&ots=InmxFd5KAX&sig=ACfU3U2BsJuvH2oay40Lrq0SZWCb-xaEdA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjizrnrnLvhAhViwsQBHYUkCdYQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22no%20weak%20form%20for%20on%22&f=false) New York, Routledge.)
- "**on** ɒn ɑ:n ɔ:n" [note, the entry makes no mention of a weak form] (from: Wells, J. C. (2008) *Longman Pronunciation Dictionary*. Harlow: Longman.)
- "The preposition *on* has no weak form" (from: Burleigh, P & Skandera P. (2016) [*A Manual of English Phonetics and Phonology*](https://books.google.ch/books?id=NPp4DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA138&lpg=PA138&dq=%22on%22+%22no+weak+form%22&source=bl&ots=Ov7dhAIEuY&sig=ACfU3U0kkgng79XbKTvaDpjedYb2SXQ8fQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwis7pjin7vhAhVNxKYKHRvFDXUQ6AEwDXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22on%22%20%22no%20weak%20form%22&f=false). Tübingen: Narr.)
- "Prepositions [...]  a few have no weak forms: *off*, *on*, *up*." (from a [handout](http://videoweb.nie.edu.sg/phonetic/courses/aae103-web/L11-weak.pdf) produced by a lecturer at the Unversity of Brunei Darussalem)
- "< on > DOES NOT HAVE A WEAK FORM REDUCED TO SHWA!" (from a [handout](http://www.kul.pl/files/30/Kursy%20na%20KUL/weakforms.pdf) produced by a lecturer at the University of Lublin, Poland)
- "The following function words have **no weak form**, no matter how unstressed they are: *did, may, might, in* /ɪn/, *on* /ɒn/, *with* /wið/, *off* /ɒf/, *up* /ʌp/" (from a scanned page of a phonology text book, found [here](http://seas3.elte.hu/coursematerial/OriPeter/07.2_BBN-ANG-242_autumn_2017_Ori.pdf))

Comment: This does not tally with my experience. In a sentence like _He went on a drinking spree_, I have always heard (and also myself pronounce) _on_ with a reduced vowel: [ʌn ~ ən ~ n̩] are all perfectly natural variants to me (the last one perhaps only possible specifically before the indefinite article).

Comment: Where are you from?

Comment: A bit of all over the place, but accent-wise roughly evenly divided between fairly generic Broadcast American and fairly generic Estuary.

Comment: Hm, well those are two radically different accents. I think your reduced pronunciation of *on* is quite unusual...  Your example sentence would likely be perceived as *He went an[d] a drinking spree.*

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Would you also find yourself dropping the 't' from want? Most of my experience of American speech is derived from film and television but I feel that a lot of Americans, even well spoken and well educated ones, would say "He wen' on a drinking spree" with the 'o' run into the truncated 'went' and weakened. This is much less likely to happen in British RP speech.

Comment: I think I agree with this answer — *ham 'n rye* would sound like *ham in rye* or *ham and rye* to me. But we generally like answers with sources here, and not just unsupported statements.

Comment: @BoldBen Yes, in AmE I would definitely drop the t in _want_ as well. Even in BrE, I’d be quite likely to do both in colloquial speech (but not if I’m being posh and speaking more RP, then I’d keep it).

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, I agree that: the reduction is more limited than with _to_, for example, but it is there in some environments.

Comment: Let me add to my previous comment that I can reduce *on* in a number of set phrases, like *out on a limb*, or *on a wild goose chase*. But not in most environments.

Comment: @PeterShor: but in those phrases, is the vowel the same as _untie_?

Comment: @KarlG: If I reduce *on* in these phrases, I would usually pronounce them with a syllabic /n/, like in *lemonade* or *ham 'n eggs* (although I guess I might put a schwa in). I pronounce *untie* with an actual vowel, /ʌ/, in it.

Comment: @PeterShor: _out'n a limb_? Do you do anything with the _t_?

Comment: The /t/ is a flap (like most /t/s before unstressed syllables). So it probably sounds like *oud'n a lim* to people not used to American accents. The *oud'n* part would sound nearly like the *oud'n* in *loud'n clear*.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yeah, fink I wood 'n' all :-)

Comment: Thinking about it more carefully, I can reduce *on* to /ən/ or /n̩/ in *out on* and *up on*, but as far as I can think of, not in any other situations. So this answer is 99% correct for me — *on* is indeed rarely reduced.

Comment: @PeterShor Can Americans pronounce it /ən/ or /ʌn/? Thanks. https://vocaroo.com/i/s0fyj6xKCI7W

Comment: @Edinburgh1: I pronounce it as /ən/ in *out on a*, *up on the*, and similar compound prepositions. But that voice clip sounds like /ɑn/, which isn't a weak form, but a perfectly valid pronunciation in certain American dialects.

Answer (score 1):

Pronunciation of the preposition or particle *on* is affected by the [*cot-caught merger*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cot%E2%80%93caught_merger), fully complete in many areas of North America, though far less so in the American South. In dialects with the merger, *on* sounds like /ɒn/ and /ɔn/ in those without.  English, Australian, and New Zealand accents generally remain unaffected while most Scottish accents have merged the other way.

In any variety of American English, the vowel in *on* never reduces to a schwa, in contrast, say, to *with*, which in rapid speech can reduce the vowel to schwa and elide the *th* if followed by the equally reduced definite article *the*. In this respect, *on* is like [*off* and *up*](https://books.google.de/books?id=NPwWCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=preposition+unreduced+vowel&source=bl&ots=mgkvXoUTmn&sig=ACfU3U0LVbZAlZ6tjb6tcgkrUykzVeaw8g&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjXyp3XsrvhAhUlMuwKHXxNAC4Q6AEwBnoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=preposition%20unreduced%20vowel&f=false), whose vowels never reduce, but unlike *to*, which does.

Comment: The first paragraph seems irrelevant, no? The question is *not* about the phonetic realization of the vowel in different American accents, but about the possibility to *reduce* the vowel when it is unstressed.

Comment: If the vowel doesn’t reduce — except, apparently, for Peter Shor — then it's pronounced like something. I provided the something.

Comment: There are American dialects without the cot-caught merger where on is pronounced /ɑ/. In fact, the line between /ɔn/ and /ɑn/ is one of those marked on [this map](https://aschmann.net/AmEng/) of American English dialects. The Midland and South pronounce it /ɔn/; the more northern dialects (including New York and Chicago) pronounce it /ɑn/.

Comment: @PeterShor: Unless my ears deceive me, those regions have the merger. Northern Cities fronts the vowel. In MI, it's especially pronounced.

Comment: Many areas with the [Northern Cities vowel shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inland_Northern_American_English#Phonology_and_phonetics) supposedly do not have the merger. It moves /ɔ/ to where /ɑ/ should be, but it fronts /ɑ/, so it gets out of the way of /ɔ/.

Comment: @KarlG Can Americans pronounce it like /ən/ or /ʌn/? Thanks for your comment. vocaroo.com/i/s0fyj6xKCI7W